# Changing ImageView at a specific desired position in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: screen shoot of my query]

In my music player android application onclick of recycler view row (or) on click of play icon which is on bottom of the page, I should be able to set the animation drawable for a specific ImageView which is currently playing. Can anyone help me out, how do I set that drawable to ImageView on position based which is currently playing?

Comment: Show what u have tried

Answer (score 1):

Declare below in Adapter class

`int currentPosition = -1;`

Set tag to your image view in onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position)
__number can be any

```
holder.albumImage.setTag(1);
```

Implement the below for onclick of view

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int PlayStopButtonState = (int) holder.albumImage.getTag();

                int previousPosition = currentPosition;
                if (PlayStopButtonState == 1) {
                    currentPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                    holder.albumImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    holder.albumImage.setTag(2);
                } else {
                    currentPosition = -1; 
                    holder.albumImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    holder.albumImage.setTag(1);
                }
                if (previousPosition != -1) {
                    notifyItemChanged(previousPosition);
                }
            }
        });
```

Finally in onBindViewHolder()

```
if(currentPosition == position ){
            holder.albumImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        } else {
            holder.albumImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter class...Define an interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void onItemClick(int position, Object item);
}
```

Implement this in your activity and in onCreate() call the below method to assign activity instance.

```
public void setListener(MyInterface clickListener) {
    this.myItemsClickListener = clickListener;
}
```

In onBindViewHolder() of Adapter class...
call the method

```
myItemsClickListener.onItemClick(position, item);
```

Note: here position is recyclerview item position and item is the object that have info of playing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Have a Look Into It**

```
public class MusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

List<MusicPojo> musicPojoList;
private static ColorStateList sColorStatePlaying;
private static ColorStateList sColorStateNotPlaying;
Context context;
String play_pause_state;

public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<MusicPojo> musicPojoList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.musicPojoList = musicPojoList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.music_list, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //boolean is to check item clicked for playing
    boolean isPlaying  = false;
    AnimationDrawable animation;
    MusicPojo musicPojo = musicPojoList.get(position);
    holder.songList.setText(musicPojo.getTrackName());
    holder.trackAlbum.setText(musicPojo.getTrackAlbum());

 //        holder.songList.setSelected(true);

    if (sColorStateNotPlaying == null || sColorStatePlaying == null) {
        initializeColorStateLists(context);
    }
    try {
        play_pause_state = MainMusicActivity.play_pause_state;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (play_pause_state != null) {
        if (play_pause_state.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
            //set boolean true to apply animation when item clicked to play
            isPlaying =true;
            AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_equalizer_white_36dp);
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(animation, sColorStatePlaying);
            holder.albumImage.setImageDrawable(animation);
            holder.albumImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            animation.start();
        } else if (play_pause_state.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            //set boolean false to not apply animation when item clicked to stop music
            isPlaying = false;
            Drawable playDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
                    R.drawable.ic_equalizer1_white_36dp);
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(playDrawable, sColorStatePlaying);
            holder.albumImage.setImageDrawable(playDrawable);
            holder.albumImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isPlaying){
              //when item is clicked to play music then apply animation for image here
                holder.albumImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.youranimationxml);
                animation = (AnimationDrawable) holder.albumImage.getBackground();
                animation.start();
            }

        }
    });

}

static private void initializeColorStateLists(Context ctx) {
    sColorStateNotPlaying = ColorStateList.valueOf(ctx.getResources().getColor(
            R.color.media_item_icon_not_playing));
    sColorStatePlaying = ColorStateList.valueOf(ctx.getResources().getColor(
            R.color.media_item_icon_playing));
}

public static void setPos(final int pos, Integer drw) {
    MyViewHolder.albumImage.setImageResource(drw);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return musicPojoList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public static TextView songList, trackAlbum;
    public static ImageView albumImage;
    private View itemView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        songList = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.musicListId);
        trackAlbum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.musicTrackAlbumId);
        albumImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumImageId);
    }
}
}



   MainActivity Class:

public class MainMusicActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Intent serviceIntent;
private Button play_pause;
private boolean isMusicPlaying = false;
RelativeLayout mediaController;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ImageView play_pause_audio, prev_song, next_song;
MusicAdapter musicAdapter;
boolean isNetworkConnected;
private static int lastPosition;
public static String play_pause_state;
private static ColorStateList sColorStatePlaying;
private static ColorStateList sColorStateNotPlaying;
MusicService musicService;
private String streamAudioLink = "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2006.mp3";
boolean bufferedBroadcastIsRegistered;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
MusicPojo musicPojo;
List<MusicPojo> musicPojoArrayList = new ArrayList<MusicPojo>();
Intent audioStatus;
// seekbar variables
private SeekBar seekBar;
private int seekMax;
private static int songEnded = 0;
boolean seekbarBroadcastRegistered;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initInitialize();

    musicAdapter = new MusicAdapter(MainMusicActivity.this, musicPojoArrayList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(musicAdapter);
    prepareAudioLinks();
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position) {

            MusicPojo moviePoj = musicPojoArrayList.get(position);
            lastPosition = position;
//                playAudio();
            if (moviePoj.getMusicUrlLink() != null) {
                serviceIntent.putExtra("setAudioLink", moviePoj.getMusicUrlLink());
                try {
                    startService(serviceIntent);
                    isMusicPlaying = true;
                    play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);
                    mediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    /*MusicService musicService = new MusicService(mediaController);
                    musicService.startService(serviceIntent);*/
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Utils.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).customToast("Not a valid file");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View v, int position) {

        }
    }));

    try {
        serviceIntent = new Intent(MainMusicActivity.this, MusicService.class);
//            setListeners();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    musicButtonClickListeners();

}

public void initInitialize() {
    mediaController = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mediaControls);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    play_pause_audio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_pause_mediaCont);
    prev_song = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mc_prev);
    next_song = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mc_next);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMC);

}

private BroadcastReceiver seekbarBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateSeekbarUI(intent);
    }
};

private void updateSeekbarUI(Intent intent) {
    String counter = intent.getStringExtra("COUNTER");
    String mediaMax = intent.getStringExtra("MEDIA_MAX");
    String songEnd = intent.getStringExtra("SONG_ENDED");

    int seekbarProgress = Integer.parseInt(counter);
    seekMax = Integer.parseInt(mediaMax);
    songEnded = Integer.parseInt(songEnd);
    seekBar.setMax(seekMax);
    seekBar.setProgress(seekbarProgress);

    if (songEnded == 1) {
        play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
    }


}

// Handling progress dialog for buffering...
public void showProgressDialog(Intent bufferIntent) {
    if (bufferIntent.getStringExtra("buffering") != null) {
        String bufferValue = bufferIntent.getStringExtra("buffering");
        int bufferIntValue = Integer.parseInt(bufferValue);

        // when broadcast value of buffering if "1" show dialog, dismiss when its "0"
        switch (bufferIntValue) {
            case 0:
           /* if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }*/
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                break;
            case 1:
//                bufferDialog();
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void changePlayPauseState(Intent musicStatusIntent) {
    if (musicStatusIntent != null) {
        if (musicStatusIntent.getStringExtra("PLAY_STATUS") != null) {
            play_pause_state = musicStatusIntent.getStringExtra("PLAY_STATUS").toString();
            if (play_pause_state.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
//                    play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);
//                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } else if (play_pause_state.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
//                    play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
//                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } else {

            }
        } else {
//                Utils.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).customToast("Null object");
        }
    }
}

public void musicButtonClickListeners() {
    play_pause_audio.setOnClickListener(MainMusicActivity.this);
    prev_song.setOnClickListener(MainMusicActivity.this);
    next_song.setOnClickListener(MainMusicActivity.this);
}

// progress dialog
private void bufferDialog() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainMusicActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Acquiring song...");
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Buffering...");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showProgressDialog(intent);
        changePlayPauseState(intent);
        audioAction(intent);
    }
};

public void setListeners() {
    play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//                playStopOnClick();
        }
    });
}

private void playStopOnClick() {
    isNetworkConnected = NetworkInformation.isNetworkConnected(MainMusicActivity.this);
    if (isNetworkConnected) {
        if (!isMusicPlaying) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).registerReceiver(seekbarBroadcast, new IntentFilter(MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
            seekbarBroadcastRegistered = true;
            play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);
//                playAudio();
            playSongBasedOnPosition(lastPosition);
            isMusicPlaying = true;

        } else {
            if (isMusicPlaying) {
 //                    play_pause.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
                stopPlaysService();
                isMusicPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        Utils.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).networkAlert();
    }
}

private void stopPlaysService() {

    // un-register seekbar broadcast

    if (seekbarBroadcastRegistered) {
        try {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(seekbarBroadcast);
            seekbarBroadcastRegistered = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    isMusicPlaying = false;
}

private void playAudio() {
    serviceIntent.putExtra("setAudioLink", streamAudioLink);
    try {
 //            musicService.setSong(musicPojoArrayList);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (bufferedBroadcastIsRegistered) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        bufferedBroadcastIsRegistered = false;
    }

    if (seekbarBroadcastRegistered) {
        try {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(seekbarBroadcast);
            seekbarBroadcastRegistered = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

//        audioStatus = new Intent(MusicService.BROADCAST_BUFFER);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        NetworkInformation.wifiSpeedTest(MainMusicActivity.this);
    }

    if (!bufferedBroadcastIsRegistered) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MusicService.BROADCAST_BUFFER));
        bufferedBroadcastIsRegistered = true;
    }
    if (play_pause_state != null) {
        if (play_pause_state.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
            isMusicPlaying = true;
            play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);
            mediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    if (!seekbarBroadcastRegistered) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).registerReceiver(seekbarBroadcast, new IntentFilter(MusicService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        seekbarBroadcastRegistered = true;
    }
    super.onResume();
}

public void prepareAudioLinks() {
    MusicPojo musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL1, 1, "Track - 01", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);
    musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL2, 2, "Track - 02", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);
    musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL3, 3, "Track - 03", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);
    musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL4, 4, "Track - 04", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);
    musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL5, 5, "Track - 05", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);
    musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL6, 6, "Track - 06", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);
    musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL7, 7, "Track - 07", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);
    musicPojo = new MusicPojo(ConstantsClass.STREAM_URL8, 8, "Track - 08", "Album Name");
    musicPojoArrayList.add(musicPojo);

    musicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void audioAction(Intent intent) {
    intent.putExtra("AUDIO_ACTION", "STOP_AUDIO");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_pause_mediaCont:
            if (play_pause_state.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
               /* play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);
//                    playSongBasedOnPosition(lastPosition);
                audioAction(audioStatus);*/
                playStopOnClick();

            } else if (play_pause_state.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                play_pause_audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
                playSongBasedOnPosition(lastPosition);
            }

            break;
        case R.id.mc_prev:
            lastPosition = (lastPosition - 1);
            if (lastPosition == -1) {
                lastPosition = 0;
                if (lastPosition < 0) {
                    Utils.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).customToast("No more songs to PLAY");
                } else {
                    playSongBasedOnPosition(lastPosition);
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.mc_next:
            lastPosition = (lastPosition + 1);
            if (lastPosition >= musicPojoArrayList.size()) {
                Utils.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).customToast("No more songs to PLAY");
            } else {
                playSongBasedOnPosition(lastPosition);
            }
            break;
    }

}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View v, int position);

    void onLongClick(View v, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    MainMusicActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MainMusicActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}

public void playSongBasedOnPosition(int pos) {
    if (musicPojoArrayList.get(pos) != null) {

        MusicPojo moviePoj = musicPojoArrayList.get(pos);
//           Utils.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).customToast(String.valueOf(musicPojoArrayList.get(pos).getMusicUrlLink()));
//                playAudio();
        if (moviePoj.getMusicUrlLink() != null) {
            serviceIntent.putExtra("setAudioLink", moviePoj.getMusicUrlLink());
            try {
                startService(serviceIntent);

                mediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    /*MusicService musicService = new MusicService(mediaController);
                    musicService.startService(serviceIntent);*/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Utils.getInstance(MainMusicActivity.this).customToast("Not a valid file");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: while pasting the code commented part was appropriate

Comment: not only on click of particular row, it should also set on click of media controller play icon which is at bottom. Any exact idea set imageview based on position?

Comment: perticular row means including your icon, wherever u click on the row the icon will get animated and u will get the clicked item position in "onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) " so u can take the position from here...if any doubts ill clear to u...

Comment: did u try putting my code? what was the result btw?

Comment: thanks for ur support still same. if i click the third position of the listrow the image is getting affected on last row.

Comment: can you print a toast in ur onItemClick with position?

Comment: Utils.getInstance(context).customToast("adapter pos :"+holder.getAdapterPosition()); i am able to get position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112770/discussion-between-ram-g-and-naveen-shriyan).